How to change the position of the text in a HTML element?
I am making a navigation bar in my website and I realized the text is just too close to the edge of the buttons. How can I fix this?

Here is the code I used:


.sections {
  height: 75px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #18148b;
  line-height: 75px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: white;
}

#sectionList {
  background-color: #131067;
  height: 100%;
  width: 500px;
}
<div id="sectionList">
  <ul id="list" style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <li id="section1" class="sections">Section1</li>
    <li class="sections">Section2</li>
  </ul>




You have to have your css something like this.
Set every element's margin and padding to 0 and box-sizing to border box.
After that you can apply required margin and padding to different tags.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#sectionList {
  background-color: #131067;
  height: 100%;
  width: 500px;
}

.sections {
  height: 75px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #18148b;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px 10px;
}
<div id="sectionList">
  <ul id="list" style="list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0">
    <li id="section1" class="sections">Section1</li>
    <li class="sections">Section2</li>
  </ul>
</div>




padding-left: 15px; /* Adds  padding */
box-sizing: border-box; /* Ensures padding doesn't increase the total width */

Add this lines to .sections class.

Just add padding to li tag in style for better control
ul#list li{padding:5px 10px 15px 20px;}

In this example, padding is top:5px, right:10px, bottom:15px and left:20px
You can set according to your requirement
